# como salir de un bucle infinito con c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Quiero saber la forma de salir de un bucle el cual debe de redireccionarme a otra parte son dos formas que necesito que es la siguiente:

1. Si encuentra vacía una consulta que tengo , entrara al bucle hasta que encuentre llena pero dejara 3 segundos entre cada retorno pero si pasan 4 veces y sigue vacío este lo sacara a otra pagina al inicio.
2. En caso de que si este lleno la consulta pues continuara con mis demás datos.

Aquí dejo el fragmento infinito de mi código, cabe mencionar que tengo un `while` que es la consulta y el otro sale del `do`:

```
        validate.Open();
            OdbcDataReader DbReader = Dbastq.ExecuteReader();

            int laagregacion =1 ;
            do
            {

                while (DbReader.Read())
                {


                    if (DbReader["MERCHANTID"] != DBNull.Value && laagregacion < 4)
                    {

                        laagregacion++;
                        Console.WriteLine(laagregacion);
                        pause (4 segudnos)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // Response.Redirect("https://www.kyocode.com");
                    }

                }

            } while (laagregacion == 0 );






            if (str_nbResponse != null && (str_nbResponse.Equals("Aprobado") || str_nbResponse.Equals("approved")))
                {
                    commando = "pay";
                    str_nb_merchant = Request.QueryString["nb_merchant"];        //16
                    if (str_nb_merchant.Length > 16)
```

Comment: Según tu código, inicializas el contador `laagregacion` en `1`. Luego, entras a un ciclo que se ejecuta mientras existan filas que leer en el `DbReader`. Si `MERCHANTID` es null, entonces, incrementas el contador y lo escribes en consola. Dónde está el ciclo infinito? El ciclo de afuera se ejecuta 1 vez porque 'laagregacion' NUNCA es 0. Y no veo un escenario donde `DbReader.Read()` sea infinito tampoco.

Comment: que tal de hecho esa variable si me funciona me esta sumando 1 cada vez que el ciclo se repita simplemente quiero saber si cuando llege a 4 este me podria sacar y redireccionar a otra pagina

Comment: Pues, sí. Se puede. `if (laagregacion ==4) // aqui redireccionas`

Comment: a yap if (DbReader["MERCHANTID"] != DBNull.Value && laagregacion < 4)
                    {

                        laagregacion++;
                        Console.WriteLine(laagregacion);
                        pause (4 segudnos)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // Response.Redirect("https://www.kyocode.com");
                    } de hecho ese me funciono solo que no continua la sentencia

Answer (score 1):

> si pasan 4 veces y sigue vacío este lo sacara a otra pagina

No entiendo por qué planteas un bucle infinito cuando está claro que quieres un bucle finito.

---

La mejor forma salir de un bucle infinito es no entrando. Dado que quieres hacer una operación hasta cuatro veces, usa un bucle `for`:

```
bool consulta_vacia = true;
for (int intento = 0; consulta_vacia && (intento != 4); ++intento)
{
    // Intentar rellenar la consulta.
    if (/* consulta tiene datos */)
        consulta_vacia = false; // Sale del bucle prematuramente
    else
        esperar_segundos(3);
}

// Llegaremos a este punto si la consulta se rellenó o se agotaron los intentos
// lo sabremos mirando la variable 'consulta_vacia'.
```

Comment: y este funciona igual ? es decir me regresa al mismo while con el que inicio y despues redirecciona a otra parte? y como puedo saber en caso de que im consulta este llena que no entre a este for?

Comment: La manera en que ese bucle `for` interactúe con código que sólo tú conoces, es algo que yo no puedo saber.

Comment: voy a reeplantear mi pregunta